# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin(\pi n x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the sequence $f_n = \sin (\pi n x)$ and I want to calculate the limit of this sequence, but I struggle with it.

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin(\pi) = 0$

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin(\pi n) = 0$

but if $x$ isn't an integer $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin (\pi n x)$ doesn't have to be $0$. So $f_n$ just diverges or should I do a discussion? I don't know.

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  Are you asking whether or not you should prove that $f_n$ is divergent if $x\notin\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Please try $x=1/2$ next and see what happens.

Comment: @Aweygan no, just to find the value of that limit.

Comment: @Somos I know, it's going to be 1 or -1 depending on $n$. So I can say just it diverges?

Comment: @Leif What is the definition of [Convergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series)? If it isn't convergent it must be divergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have some amount of mathematical competency so would like to leave the following hint,
$$ \sin(\pi n x) = \sin\left(\pi n \left(\lfloor x\rfloor + x_{frac} \right) \right) $$
Where $x_{frac}$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than equal to $x$.

Let me know if you want the complete solution(I would have to work behind it as well).

***edit:*** The main idea is that you want to break it into parts that is a multiple of $\pi$ and something that is less than $\pi$. After doing so you can focus solely on the later part.

Comment: You may need to use a modified floor function.

Comment: I must say that this approach doesn't really lead us anywhere. You can instead extend the definition of $\sin(\theta) = \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}$ and then show convergence. If I did my working correctly, it seems to converge to $0$ as $\lim {n \rightarrow \infty}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x\in (0,1).$ Let $A$ be the arc $\{e^{it}: t\in [\pi/2-\pi (x/2), \pi/2+\pi (x/2)]\}.$ Note $A$ is centered at $i$ and has length equal to $\pi x.$ It's good to draw a picture and think of the situation geometrically.

Now the points $e^{in\pi x}, n = 1,2,\dots,$ march around the unit in steps of arc length $\pi x.$ Because the length of $A$ is exactly the same as the length of any step, at least once in every orbit of the circle we must have $e^{in\pi x}\in A$ for some $n.$ It follows that $e^{in\pi x}\in A$ for infinitely many $n.$

With exactly the same argument, you can see this is also true of the arc $A'$ of the same length centered at $-i.$ It follows that $\sin(n\pi x)\ge \sin(\pi/2-\pi (x/2))$ for infinitely many $n,$ and $\sin(n\pi x)\le -\sin(\pi/2-\pi (x/2))$ for infinitely many $n.$

This shows that the full sequence $\sin(n\pi x)$ diverges. Again, this was for $0<x<1.$ But using a little bit of symmetry and $2\pi$-periodicity shows $\sin(n\pi x)$ diverges for every $x\in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z.$